# scala test any() for polymorphic method

Tags: scala, function, scalatest, any

```
mockedObj = mock[Obj]
when(mockedObj.someMethod(anyString, any(_))).thenAnswer(
  new Answer[Unit] {
    override def answer(invocationOnMock: InvocationOnMock): Unit = {
      // whatever
    }
  }
)
```

This someMethod is expecting a String, and a function. The someMethod has several implementations, where the functions received are different. This is why I am trying to use any(_) on that 'when' statement.

The error I get is:

```
Error:(26, 49) missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => any(x$1))
when(mockedObj.someMethod(anyString(), any(_))).thenAnswer(
                             ^
```

I am not aware if there is a way to place something like 'any' for functions in an abstract way, since I am not concerned in checking that parameter, but I need the mock to pass regardless the function.

Thanks!!

Comment: You have to mock each variation separately. They are all their own separate functions, despite being named the same way. There is no way you can mock all of them at once with a single stub.